# PHP Multidimensional Array Build

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to build a multidimensional array in a loop and I am stumped as to why this code does not work

```
<?php

$users = array(35,25,45,34,56,67);

$months = array('smelly','stinky','chubby','grubby','nubby','funky');

foreach($users as $user){

    $mdata[$user] = array();

    foreach($months as $month){

    array_push($mdata[$user][],$month);

    }

}

print_r($mdata);

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be:

```
array_push($mdata[$user],$month);
```

Comment: You rock Guillaume! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is generally better to use `$arr[] = $data`, because there is no need to call a function.

```
foreach($months as $month){
    $mdata[$user][] = $month ; //Just use the shorthand
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to better describe what *doesn't work* mean and what exactly you want to achieve (maybe example result?)  However this line here:

```
array_push($mdata[$user][],$month);
```

seems odd.  If I were to guess, you want it to be

```
array_push($mdata[$user],$month);
```

or

```
$mdata[$users][] = $month;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra [] at the array_push, try:

```
array_push($mdata[$user],$month);
```